If $\nabla$ is a connection and $u:M\to\mathbb{R}$ a smooth function, is $\nabla^n u = d^n u$ for any $n$?
From Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds:

Example 4.22 (The Covariant Hessian). Let $u$ be a smooth function on $M$. Then $\nabla u \in \Gamma(T^{(0,1)}TM) = \Omega^1(M)$ is just the 1-form $du$, because both tensors have the same action on vectors: $\nabla u(X) = \nabla_X u = Xu = du(X)$. The 2-tensor $\nabla^2 u = \nabla (du)$ is called the covariant Hessian of $u$.

Just a short clarification: can't we apply $\nabla$ repeately to get
$$\nabla^n u = d^n u$$
for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

No, in general, $\nabla^{n}u$ is a $(0,n)$-tensor field, but for $n\geq 3$ neither symmetric nor antisymmetric. So the result can not be written in terms of the exterior derivative. Furthermore, $d^{n}u=0$ since $d^{2}=0$.

To emphasize, once you get past functions ($0$-forms), a connection depends on lots more than $d$.
